# Circular L'Hopitals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{(R^2+x^2)^{1/2}} $

Attempted applying L'Hopital's Rule to this limit but after two applications I end up up back at the beginning. Am I missing something?

Note: $R$ is a constant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need L'Hospital here:

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2+x^2}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2(\frac{R^2}{x^2} + 1)}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{x^2} + 1}}$$

From there, you can use the fact that $x>0$ meaning $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=x$ to calculate the limit easily.

Answer (score 1):

Or: first compute
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{(R^2+x^2)}
$$
using l'Hopital's rule, then take the square root of your result.

Answer (score 0):

write your Limit as $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{(x^2)^{1/2}(\frac{R}{x^2}+1)^{1/2}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{|x|}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{R}{x^2}+1\right)^{1/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

With *equivalents* :

$\bigl(R^2+x^2\bigr)^{1/2}\sim_\infty \lvert x\rvert $, so
$$\frac{x}{\bigl(R^2+x^2\bigr)^{1/2}}\sim_\infty \frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\,x>0,\\-1&\text{if }\,x<0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, but this is very confusing. What do you mean by “if $x>0$”? The limit is at $\infty$, so you can very well *assume* to only be dealing with $x>0$.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I didn't check if I had any typo  – and I often have.  For the case $x<0$, I wasn't sure whether, in the O.P.'s post $ \infty$ denoted $+\infty$ or $\pm\infty$. As I had both for the same price, I chose the maximal solution… Thanks for pointing the typo!

Comment: It's still confusing.

Comment: @egreg: But it's only a sketch! What's confusing exactly?

Comment: There is no “$x$”: it's a limit. The confusion about $\pm\infty$ and $\infty$ should disappear from earth.

Comment: Precisely: I imply that if the function is equivalent to a non-zero constant, this constant is the limit. For the confusion, I've  always be used for *real* functions to specify $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Unless one lives on a projective line, there's a difference…

Comment: @Bernard, I agree with you on the completeness of your answer. Should not $\sqrt{R^2}$ be just $R^2$?

Comment: @FarrukhAtaev: Yes! I was thinking of coding the whole square root, I guess and was out of my mind. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: If they could calculate the equivalents they would not have posted this question.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Well, I show them how simpler it is in many cases. Every well-bred young people should know about equivalents, in my opinion.